# How can I use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to add pin on user location?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am making an app that adds a pin on the map , and so far it has been adding the pin where the user does the long press, but I would like it to change and add it on the user location instead, however, I don't know what to change to make it happen, could you please correct my code to make it work? 
thank you , I added my code below:

```
var uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")

    uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0

    Map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)

}

func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

        var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.Map)

        var newCoordinate = self.Map.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.Map)

        var location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude , longitude: newCoordinate.longitude)
```

this is the user location code I am using:

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

        var latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        var longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

        var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

        var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

        var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)

        self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    }
```

Comment: instead of adding the location of the touch in your action() function, just change it add the location of the user location if its available through self.Map.userLocation

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JoshHamet Do you mean like this? var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.self.Map.userLocation, if so, it says UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not have a member called "Map"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your long press is triggered, just add an annotation object to your map which is a lightweight, model object corresponding to the data your pin will hold.

```
let annotation = MKAnnotation();
annotation.title = "My location";
annotation.coordinate = self.Map.userLocation.location.coordinate;
self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation);
```

After you add the annotation, make sure you're registered to the delegate of your map view and it will ask you to supply a view for the annotation you added.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView!,
    viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!{
    if(annotation is MKUserLocation){
         return nil;
    }
    let pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationForIdentifier("MyIdentifier");
    let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation,reuseIdentifier:"MyIdentifier");
   return pinAnnotationView;
}
```

I'm sure there's some syntax issues but hopefully you understand the logic. Create a annotation for the location of the user. This triggers the protocol method of you map view and supply your pin annotation view there with the annotation attached.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , however I do need a pin because I am doing some things with these pins afterwards